# proving a function is a bijection from the positive integers to itself

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

> For each positive integer $n,$ let $d(n)$ denote its greatest odd divisor. Let $a_1 = 1$, and $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ for $n\ge 1,$ where $f(n) = \frac{n}{d(n)} + \frac{n}2$ if $n$ is even and $2^{(n+1)/2}$ otherwise. Prove that the function $g : \mathbb{Z}^+\to \mathbb{Z}^+, g(n)=a_n$ is a bijection. Find $g^{-1}(1992)$.

I know some properties of the function $f$ and sequence $a_n$ that can easily be proved via induction. For instance, $f^m(2^n) = 2^{n-m} (2m+1)$ for all positive integers $1\leq m\leq n.$ Also, $a_{n(n+1)/2 + 1} = 2^n$ for all positive integers $n$. In order to prove that $g$ is a bijection, then I think I can proceed inductively and show that all of the numbers $a_{n(n+1)/2 + 2},\cdots , a_{(n+1)(n+2)/2 + 1}$ are distinct from $a_1,\cdots, a_{n(n+1)/2 + 1}$. But I'm not sure how to show this; it seems like it might be useful to show that no two of the given numbers can have the same value of $d(n)$ and the same highest power of 2 dividing them.

These properties can be used to show that $g^{-1}(1992) = 8253,$ since $a_{(127)(128)/2 + 1} = 2^{127}$ and $f^{124}(2^{127}) = 1992$.

Comment: You can already show $g$ is surjective using the properties of $f$ you mention. As to injectivity: if $a_n=a_m$ for some $n\neq m$, then the sequence is periodic with finite period, and in particular $g$ takes on finitely many distinct values. This contradicts surjectivity.

Comment: This is a frighteningly fantastic sequence and an amazing example of non-intuitive parts of set theory. The $k$th "cycle" produces $k-1$ even numbers but only one odd number; nonetheless the sequence contains all of the integers. As to proof, I think you can show surjectivity from the fact that every value from $a_{T_m +2}$ to $a_{T_{m+1}-1}$ is double the value of $a_{T_{m-1}+1}$ to $a_{T_m}$, and that $a_{T_m +1}$ is $2^m$, for all $m$. ($T_m$ being the triangular numbers.)

Comment: @Fred Are you still interested? If yes, then I will try to answer.